# Javascript scrollTop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, offset, scrolltop

I have this code:

```
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery(".woocommerce-breadcrumb").offset().top
}, 777);
```

But when executed it scrolls too much, how can I make it scroll by 30px less when there is no other element that I could use?

Thank you

Comment: Add 30 to the value you have?

Comment: Either of which would have taken a few seconds to try, as opposed to asking… I strongly suggest trying things & doing some research before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're scrolling to the `.offset().top` of the `woocommerce-breadcrumb` element, you can subtract some pixels from that offset.

Small example were there's a scroll button *below* the `woocommerce-breadcrumb`. When clicked, we'll scroll to the top of the element **plus 200px**, so eventually the scroll will stop 200 pixels **below** the top of the element.

```js
$('button').on('click', () => {
  jQuery('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: jQuery(".woocommerce-breadcrumb").offset().top + 200
  }, 777);
});
```

```css
.woocommerce-breadcrumb {
  height: 3000px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class='woocommerce-breadcrumb'>Scroll down for the scroll-button</div>

<button>Scroll</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes, vanilla JS does what you want. Just use [`scrollIntoView()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView):

```
jQuery(".woocommerce-breadcrumb").get(0).scrollIntoView();
```